# Pretty urls not redirecting in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pretty-urls

I have an action name cart in site controller and I have used pretty URL so my URL is

```
WWW.test.com/cart
```

But I want to redirect if someone enter `WWW.test.com/cart/`, 
then it should be redirected to `WWW.test.com/cart`.
I don't have cart controller.

Comment: If you are saying you want to remove the trailing slash, you have a choice to make, here you will find some options for a solution: https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/handling-trailing-slash-in-urls.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`UrlNormalizer`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer) for that:

```
'urlManager' => [
    // ...
    'normalizer' => [
        'class' => yii\web\UrlNormalizer::class,
    ],
],
```

See [documentation about URL normalization](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-normalization) for more info.